# How to tackle an error that occurred when running npm install command from Windows

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to install and run an application on Windows 7. When I run `npm install` as required by the application, I'm faced with the error below. It seems its a node-gyp and Visual Studio error.

How can I fix it?

```
C:\Users\`>cd C:\publik

C:\publik>npm install

> tiny-secp256k1@1.1.0 install C:\publik\node_modules\tiny-secp256k1
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\publik\node_modules\tiny-secp256k1>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin
\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Program
 Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )

gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
gyp ERR! find VS could not use PowerShell to find Visual Studio 2017 or newer
gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
gyp ERR! find VS - not found
gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modu
les\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:121:47)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node
-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:74:16
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Program Files\
nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:344:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node
-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:70:14
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node
-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:365:16
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node
-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node
-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:302:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:209:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodej
s\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\publik\node_modules\tiny-secp256k1
gyp ERR! node -v v12.10.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.8 (node_modules\fse
vents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@
1.2.8: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"ia32"
})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! tiny-secp256k1@1.1.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the tiny-secp256k1@1.1.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional log
ging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\`\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-11-25T01_51_54_204Z
-debug.log
```

Comment: It tells you exactly: "You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio including the "Desktop development with C++" workload. For more information consult the documentation at: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows"

Comment: Thanks Joe, You can update this as answer.